# Getting the Value of Radio Button

Tags: html, angularjs

**Edit:**
I am getting `undefined` when I tried to submit the `ng-model` of the `radio`.
Sample code in my `submit button`:

```
 ng-click="addSubscriber(plan)"
```

Tried to `console.log(plan)` inside the `addSubscriber()` but getting `undefined`.

---

I am having headache because of the problem of getting the selected value of radio button. The value is showing and it is rendering `radio` depends on my `data`. But `ng-model` doesn't work, I can't get the value of selected `radio`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <div ng-repeat="plan in plans" class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" ng-model="plan.plan" value="{{plan.plan_code}}" name="plan.plan_name">{{plan.plan_name | capitalize}}
          </label>
       </div>
    </div>
    <pre>{{plan.plan}}</pre>
</div>
```

No value is showing in `<pre>` tag. I searched and tried some posted answers in other topics but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Another problem was that the `ng-model` inside the `ng-repeat` was unable to update the controller variable, this is due to that fact that.

> `ng-repeat` directive creates a new scope.

Thus we need to change the `ng-model` from `chosenPlan` to `$parent.chosenPlan`, which will update the parent scope instead.

In the above scenario, the input radio buttons need to be set under a common name for them to act as group of radio buttons. The value of the radio button also needs to be set to a common variable which can be used in the submit function.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.chosenPlan" ng-value="plan.plan_code" name="test"/>
        {{plan.plan_name | capitalize}}
</label>
```

In the above form we can see that the `ng-model` is set to a common variable. The group name `name` attribute is set to a common name.

Please find below a working model of the same.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**Old Answer:**

The `<pre>` tag lies outside the `ng-repeat` move it inside, change the value to `ng-value` as shown below. Name for it to have the proper value should be `name="{{plan.plan_name}}"`. Let me know if you face any issues.

```
<div ng-controller='MyController'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div ng-repeat="plan in plans" class="radio">
        <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="plan.plan" ng-value="plan.plan_code" name="{{plan.plan_name}}"/>{{plan.plan_name | capitalize}}
        </label>
        <pre>{{plan.plan}}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mocked up the data and providing an example for reference:

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: but why when I submitting the `ng-model` value I am getting `undefined`?

Comment: @Marksmanship Can you replicate the issue in the JSFiddle I shared, will help you resolve this!, I need the submit function alone I think where you get the undefined!

Comment: Thank you very much for the well explained answer. The exact answer that I have been looking for. You made my headache gone away. Really appreciate your help and time. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<pre>{{plan.plan}}</pre>` is out of the scope of the ng-repeat so plan.plan is unrecognized. If you would like to show a value for each radio button, you can try it like that -

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div ng-repeat="plan in plans" class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" ng-change="radioChanged()" ng-model="plan.plan" value="{{plan.plan_code}}" name="plan.plan_name">{{plan.plan_name}}
        </label>
        <pre>{{plan.plan}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also added a 'ng-change' function, so you can try to put some debugger inside that function and watch the changed value inside your controller.

Comment: but why when I submitting the ng-model value I am getting undefined? I have updated my question. thanks,